# GOOGLE API CLIENT "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Sheets' not found in /home/mybinptf/public_html/laravel/quickstart.php"

Tags: php, json, google-api, composer-php

I'm trying to get started with the integration of Google Api php quick starter. I intend using it for a vote by text campaign.

The files `Quickstart.php` and `composer.json` are located inside laravel folder.
I installed composer via namecheap cpanel.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
```

Comment: Show us your composer.json and have a look whether the file `vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Sheets.php` exists

Comment: {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },  @nico haase

Comment: Please add it in readable format to your question

Comment: And what about the other question, does `vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Sheets.php` exist?

Comment: i can't seem to find it...it doesn't exist. Nico Haase

Comment: So, you probably have to run `composer update` to install it

Comment: Thank you Nick Haase I'll do as you directed.